# Using viewbox parameter for restricting geocode search area

Tags: php, geocoding

I'm trying to use the viewbox parameter from the LocationIQ API to shrink the area my geocoded results are searched in.

I have visualised the area here:
https://codepen.io/honk007/pen/abaqPPP

Looks like I'm not getting the viewbox parameter correct. The documentation says:

> The preferred area to find search results. Any two corner points of
> the box - max_lon,max_lat,min_lon,min_lat or
> min_lon,min_lat,max_lon,max_lat - are accepted in any order as long as
> they span a real box.

There is also a tool, where a bounding box can be drawn:
https://norbertrenner.de/osm/bbox.html

So I'm passing this: `&viewbox=1,38.2,5.5,40.5` but the results are not comming from the restricted area.

Comment: Have you added `bounded=1` as well? Questions like this should come with _proper_ information ([mre]), and not just fragments.

Comment: yes, i also added bounded=1, but still getting results from a different area.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it by using correct ordering of bounding box arguments like described here:
https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Bounding_Box

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).